# FFMPEG Combining two videos that are same size but different SAR/DAR?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying combine two videos but I keep getting an error stating:

```
"Input link in 1:v0 parameters (size 320x480, SAR 2:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (320x480, SAR 1:1)"
```

Since the sizes are the same, I'm confused by they have different ratios?  If you can't tell I am very new to FFMPEG.

My FFMPEG Version is: **ffmpeg version N-89439-g1215889bc1**

I am calling FFMPEG as follows:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i transition_12984.mp4 -i PIP_12984_complete.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_12984.mp4
```

I figure it would be helpful to have the files I am combining:

- [PIP_12984_complete.mp4](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtiXKZF_BIouohBWAyzh7674GWGB)
- [transition_12984.mp4](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtiXKZF_BIouog8q4NkCC7YUE3WZ)

Again I am very new so please let me know any other information required to help me!  I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SARs are different. You can ignore it,

```
ffmpeg.exe -i transition_12984.mp4 -i PIP_12984_complete.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=unsafe=1:n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_12984.mp4
```

Comment: This almost works. Almost because some videos stretch. Do you know how to fix the stretching?

Comment: I have the same ratio for all videos but the SAR error occurs. This method allows to finish the conversion, but few seconds of video frames are missing in the middle.